# Dúvida Json MVC Core Razor

Tags: ajax, json, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Criei um método para realizar um `Insert` através de `Ajax`, dessa forma:

```
function SalvarHorario() 
{

    //NomeHorario
    var nome = $("#Nome").val();

    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    var tokenadr = 
        $('form[action="/Horario/Create"] input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    var headers = {};
    var headersadr = {};
    headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
    headersadr['__RequestVerificationToken'] = tokenadr;

    //Gravar
    var url = "/Horario/Create";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , type: 'POST'
        , headers: headersadr
        , data: { Id: 0, Nome: nome, __RequestVerificationToken: token }
        , success: function (data) {
            //if (data.Resultado > 0) {
            ListarItens(data.Resultado);
            //}
        }
    });
}
```

Só que ele não reconhece o método CREATE que eu chamo no Action, a página que eu estou pegando os dados, foi criada por Razor CRUD.
Ele só inclui através da classe automática que é criada:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.Horarios.Add(Horarios);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Eu criei um controller, e preciso q ele busque o método desse controller, já tentei mudar de nome, e nada da certo, segue como é o método que preciso que chame:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Horarios h)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
           _context.Horarios.Add(h);
           _context.SaveChanges();
     }
     return Json(new { Resultado = h.Id });
 }
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Se eu tiro esse código `public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()` ele me retorna erro do ***Bad Request 400***.

Já tentei várias formas nenhuma funciona, estou aprendendo `MVC Core Entity Framework` agora, então ainda estou apanhando muito.

Comment: Você está usando `Razor Pages`?

Comment: Estou sim!! É como se ele n reconhecesse a função create!! Ainda sou nova com mvc ..

Comment: O Razor Pages é diferente do MVC Controller !!! Você vai precisar escolher o projeto correto, porque no MVC tem um comportamento diferente do Razor Pages.

Comment: Você tem algum exemplo que possa me ajudar ? O estranho é que ele entra na função, e logo em seguida tem mais 3 funções, e ele realiza elas, porque só essa create q ele n reconhece ?? A diferença do create para a outra é a passagem do Id pra função json..

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio e https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.0 esses dois links pode te ajudar, mas, lembrando que Razor Page trabalha com convenção e o MVC não, se misturou um no outro esse foi o problema, o método create não vai funcionar mesmo ...!!! (dessa forma)

Comment: Virgilio verificando aqui, ele entra na função, coloquei um alert após o sucess, e ele aparece normal, ele só não inclui, aparentemente não encontrei nenhum problema com a função.

Comment: Se tem que debugar o código serve side! já fez isso?

Comment: Ele só inclui se tiver o código de incluir do entityframework  as outras funções funcionam, que são chamadas logo após esta, como posso pegar o id então ? Se eu pegar o ID no include, já resolve o meu problema.

Comment: tem que ver o código por inteiro...

Comment: public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync() essa função que inclui, funciona, e entre entra na SalvarHorario, coloquei um alert, só que preciso que ele pegue o ID do último horário salvo.

Comment: deveria ser assim: `public IActionResult OnPostResult()
{
            return new JsonResult(new { Resultado = Horarios.Id });
}`

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.